# How do I changed the color of a specific datagrid row referenced in a numericupdown

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and integer numericupdown in a MVVM pattern. My users have asked that as numericupdown is changed, the background color of the corresponding row is also changed.

I cannot change the grid's SelectedIndex to do the highlighting.

Comment: What is the link to select the row based numeric box. It is only the number. So only thing we can think of selectedIndex. But you dont want selectedIndex. Then tell me some other link between the number box and the datagrid row link some ID in the object which can be compared to find the selecteditem.

Comment: That is the question I am asking. I was hoping that I could bind an array to something in the datagrid, where each element in the array would control the color of a corresponding row in the grid. I may have to implement this in code behind, which would be admitting defeat for me, but my users don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="{x:Static system:Int32.MaxValue}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <wpfApplication2:EqualsMultiConverter x:Key="EqualsMultiConverter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualsMultiConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Path="ViewModelPropertyBoundToNumericUpDown" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCC" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Basically, we set alternation index to a sufficiently large number so it becomes the row number. We then compare it to the number in the numeric up down using this converter:

```
public class EqualsMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Equals(values[0], values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that maybe NumericUpDown returns `double` and not `int`, in which case, you might need to cast the two values to the same type in the converter code.